# sizeof Java object

Tags: java, sizeof

How can we find out the size of a Java object?

Example:

```
class Person{
    String name;  
    int age;  

    public Person(String n, int a){  
        name = n;  
        age = a;  
    }
}  

Person person = new Person("Andy", 30);
```

How can I know the size of person object?

Comment: Why do you need to know the size of the object?

Comment: If you really need to know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: consider the scenario where we have limited memory and application has multiple objects taking up space, how would we then identify which object is taking more space and handle accordingly.

Comment: limited memory could be anywhere, perhaps my desktop/laptop in relation to the application I am running

Comment: @leaner, I can tell you this data structure is tiny for a desktop.  So small you shouldn't be worrying about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is not meaningful, at least not without further context.

The notion of "size" in Java is only reasonably well defined for primitives: A byte is 8 bit (unsurprisingly) an `int` is 32 bit, a `long` 64bit, etc. (see e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for a full list).

For object instances, it's more complicated, because:

- Object instances can (and usually will) contain references to other instances internally, so you must decide whether to count these dependent instances, and how. What if several instances share a dependency?
- Sometimes, object instances may be reused (e.g. interning of `java.lang.String`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning ). So if you use x objects of size y, the total size may be smaller than x*y
- The JVM has a lot of leeway about how to implement objects and instances internally.
  It may use different techniques for different instances (e.g. sharing internal data structures), so there may not even be a meaningful "size" to assign to a single object.

Maybe you could explain why you are interested in object sizes.

There are some rules of thumb for estimating the heap memory used by instances (e.g. in the Sun JVM, a `java.lang.Object` instance uses 8 byte), but these will depend on the JVM you use.

Generally, if you want to know about your heap usage, use a memory / heap profiler.

*Edit:*

Well, there is (as of JDK 6) a way to get an approximation of the amount of memory used by an object: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29

It's still only an approximation...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get something that might help you if you do something like this:

```
    /* First trigger classloading */
    MyObject delegate = new MyObject();

    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    long before = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    MyObject delegate2 = new MyObject();
    long after = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    System.out.println("Memory used:"+(before-after));
```

This will hopefully give you the answer you want, or at least an approximation.

Comment: What about multi-threaded situations? If two objects of the same size are allocated at the same time, then the value of memory used will be twice the size wanted.

Comment: I'd make a small controlled test for the objects I want to messure. If you do this in a threaded environment, then all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

EhCache provides a [SizeOf](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/pool/sizeof/SizeOf.html) class that will try to use the [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) agent and will fall back to a different approach if the agent is not loaded or cannot be loaded ([details here](http://codespot.net/2012/01/04/measuring-java-object-sizes/)).

Also see [the agent from Heinz Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue142.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sizeof4j](https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/sizeof4j) library to calculate the size of any object in java like `SizeOf.shallowSize(new Integer(2))`

Answer (score 0):

> Objects. To determine the memory usage of an object, we add the amount
>   of memory used by each instance variable to the overhead associated
>   with each object, typically 16 bytes. The overhead includes a
>   reference to the object’s class, garbage collection information, and
>   synchronization information. Moreover, the memory usage is typically
>   padded to be a multiple of 8 bytes (machine words, on a 64-bit
>   machine). For example, an Integer object uses 24 bytes (16 bytes of
>   overhead, 4 bytes for its int instance variable, and 4 bytes of
>   padding)

Reference : [http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-4th-Edition-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X)

Answer (score -3):

Java has no built in `sizeof` operator.

You could try and use a serialization method, by serializing an object to memory and getting the size of that data, but that wouldn't necessarily be the size you want.

You could also have a method called `sizeOf()`, like this:

```
// returns the size of this object in bytes
int sizeOf()
{
     int size = 0;
     size += name.Length * 2; // each character in name is 2 bytes, no?
     size += 4; // for n, which is 32 bits = 4 bytes
}
```

Note that this implementation doesn't include the metadata inside name, only the number of bytes necessary to make the `char[]` for it.

Comment: But also this wouldn't show how much space headers or so take.

Comment: Edited, I added that information... honestly, I don't think that Java was ever intended to have a function like that...

Comment: I believe serialization is not the precise way of doing it, since it adds metadata with objects so that de-serialization process knows how to reconstructs the object

Comment: Correct. The second method is more accurate, but still, why would you need to know the size of an object.. is this size similar to the C/C++ `sizeof`?

Comment: @Richard, I have no idea, RD just gave one link above, check that out, that seems good!

Comment: The size of a serialized object may differ a lot from the memory used by the object instance. String are e.g. serialized using UTF-8 encoding, but in-memory, the String instances are using UTF-16 internally (at least in Oracle's VM).

Comment: I said that in my answer :) yes, it isn't perfect, but java I do not think was truly intended to have such a function..