# Is sizeof a keyword in Java

Tags: java, sizeof

I think this is a simple question: Is sizeof is a keyword in Java? Some people also say call it an operator, some call it a method, and some call it a command.
  What is it?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+java+keywords) turns up an [authoritative list of Java keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) as the second hit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof java object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115239/sizeof-java-object)

Comment: There's a standard and you can see what language they use in there to describe `sizeof`. Of course, what it is and what it's called are two different questions.

Comment: @user2357112 The question is within the context of C and C++ as per the tags.

Comment: @Sparks: That's because the questioner changed the language the question was about in version 5 of the question.

Comment: Don't completely change a question. Thanks.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Sorry..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is an operator (and keyword) in C#.  It's not in Java.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ and C, it's both [an operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) and [a keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/sizeof).