# How to get how much space a Method or a return value used?

Tags: java, return, heap-memory

Is it possible to know/get how much space/memory are used when a method is executed or when there is a return value? I don't want to know how much space used by the app, just some code like method or the return value. I  tried the runtime.getRuntime, but from my understanding, It looks like it tells me how much space is used by the entire code/app, am I right?

EDIT :

```
  public int [] randtotal(int times2)
    {
        int in1[] = new int[times2];
        for (int i = 0; i<Num2; i++)
        Random rand = new Random();
        {
            in1[times2]= rand.NextInt(5);
        }

        totalNum(in1);
        return int1;
    }
```

As you can see here, at the end of the code there is the "return int1;" , so I want to know when these code is executed how much space is allocated for the value here?

Comment: "The method _or_ the return value"? It's hard to understand what you really mean with this. Care to show an example?

Comment: Options include: 1) Use a profiler externally. 2) Take the difference between measurements of used memory internally. 3) Estimate the size of objects as discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115239/sizeof-java-object .

Comment: You should add your code samples by editing your question not in the comments :)

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I already add the sample code, thanks.

Comment: `int inputData[] = new int[Num2]` - As you're creating an int Array here, the   memory occupied by this Array depends on the value of `Num2` here. Let's say `Num2` is 10 i.e you're creating an array of 10 ints - so it will be `12 bytes (Header) + 4 bytes (length) + 10 * 4 bytes (each int is 4 bytes) = 56 bytes`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation, but is there a way you can get the 56 bytes answer with a code? Something like sizeof or runtime.getRuntime maybe?

Comment: You can try Java Object Layout API from [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/). I cannot assure you that it returns exactly 56 bytes from code :)

Comment: But I think you will get even better picture if you use a profiling tool like VisualVM , Eclipse MAT or YourKit Java Profiler (Commercial). You can use any of these tools, take a Heap Snapshot and then analyze object sizes, instance count and several other metrics :)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir and anyone else that reply to this problem, I will try your suggestion and see if it works for me. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visualvm tool to profile the overall application and you can also profile certain package, class or function

see this link :
https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir and thanks for the link, but is it possible to measure/calculate/get the space allocated with a code? an alternative to runtime.getRuntime?

Comment: @user5397881 no because that is implementation dependent and not specified in the JLS.

Comment: @ArtB oh, Thanks alot sir.